# Get string Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

how do you get the string or decipher "path" if the code is like this?

```
<body>

    <path d="M44.4,11.5C44.4,11.5,44.4,11.5,44.4,11.5l-9.9,0C34.3,5.1,29.7,0,24,0S13.7,5.1,13.5,11.5H3.6v0</path>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the node by,

```
string valueOfD = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body/path").GetAttributeValue("d", "");
```

where `doc` is your main `HtmlDocument`.

**NOTE**

you are missing the closing double quote at the end of the string along with closing `>`. It should be like,

```
<path d="M44.4,234"></path>
```